# Detecting epoxy in a polyester powder coat paint

Tags: organic-chemistry, polymers

I have 2 steel parts which were both powder coated in a polyester powder coat, however one of them does not perform exactly as I would expect it in my unusual use case which depends on temperature. I *suspect* this is because the well-performing one contains epoxy - but I am not sure. I would like to sort of narrow down my options for ordering new parts.

Both parts look virtually identical, and unfortunately I only have 1 of the well performing part, which I also need to use constantly.

**Is there a *reasonably accessible (common household/industrial chemicals or tools)* way to detect if either of the powder coats contains epoxy, without it being triggered by polyester, either chemical or otherwise?**

From what I gathered, acetone would dissolve both of them, so that likely won't yield any results without some detailed analysis.

Comment: Can you scrap a little the one that is working better? The idea is to take a sample and run some analysis. The most simple one will be an FTIR. [Here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/227327777_Synthesis_and_characterization_of_oligosalicylaldehyde-based_epoxy_resins) is an example.

Answer (score -1):

You should mix both in some acidified ethanol mixture. Acid can be muriatic acid. Water and dilute acid will hydrolyze epoxy to a diol but won't be able to break ester.
This diol when reacted with periodic acid will release a ketone which you can then apply a tollen's test for.